# Postgresql - Hot standby vs Streaming

Tags: postgresql, replication, standby

I'm trying to understand the various PostgreSQL replication technologies. But still I am unable to understand difference between Hot Standby and Streaming Replication.

[In this Blog](http://bajis-postgres.blogspot.in/2014/04/difference-between-warm-hot-standby-and.html) the Hot Standby and Streaming replication is same.  Can anyone help me understand this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The blog post is using the terms incorrectly.

Those are two different things.

"Hot Standby" is the state the replica is in and means it is available for read-only queries. A replica can also "just" be a standby, but then it does not allow queries, it just sits there and waits to take over.

A replica needs to have exactly the same data as the master and the way the data is sent from the master to the replica is what "streaming replication" refers to.

A hot standby can also be setup using log shipping (sometimes also referred to as "continuous WAL archiving") or even streaming replication together with log shipping.

[Quote from the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/warm-standby.html)

> In standby mode, the server continuously applies WAL received from the master server. The standby server can read WAL from a WAL archive or directly from the master over a TCP connection (streaming replication).